# Is it possible to specify a hexadecimal number in LLVM IR code?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

For example:

```
error: floating point constant invalid for type
      %3 = and i8 0x80, %2
                  ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a scan of the [IR reference manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#simple-constants), it looks like hexadecimal literals are reserved for the representation of floating point numbers that cannot be exactly represented in a reasonable number of digits.

Which explains why your error message says that the `floating point constant` is invalid.

Comment: Nowadays you can prefix the integer with `u` and it works, so `%3 = and i8 u0x80, %2` should be valid