# have llvm::Module::dump print integers in hex

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

When I call `llvm::Module::dump` it prints integer constants in decimal. For example:

```
%1 = load float, float* inttoptr (i64 4404658304 to float*)
```

Is there a way I can tell it to format with hex? Presumably the IR syntax allows for hex integer constants.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Is it possible to specify a hexademical number in LLVM IR code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310509/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-hexademical-number-in-llvm-ir-code), hex is reserved for floating point literals. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Without patching llvm it is NOT possible.

if you are open to patch llvm then you can modify lib/IR/AsmWriter.cpp:1084

```
 static void WriteConstantInternal(raw_ostream &Out, const Constant *CV,
                                    TypePrinting &TypePrinter,
                                    SlotTracker *Machine,
                                    const Module *Context) {
    if (const ConstantInt *CI = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(CV)) {
      if (CI->getType()->isIntegerTy(1)) {
        Out << (CI->getZExtValue() ? "true" : "false");
        return;
      }
      Out << CI->getValue();
      return;
    }
```

here you can patch code to below to dump integers to hex.

```
-     Out << CI->getValue();
+     Out << format_hex(CI->getZExtValue(), 0, /*Upper=*/true);
```

Comment: I was thinking of just dumping to a string and just searching for "i64 [integer]", so I don't have to change anything in LLVM.

Comment: You haven't mentioned you final goal so, if it works for you then cheers.